Improve JOLT config
I've a JSON like this:
{
   "result":{
      "BidModifiers":[
         {
            "AdGroupId":5462325568,
            "Level":"AD_GROUP",
            "Type":"DESKTOP_ADJUSTMENT",
            "DesktopAdjustment":{
               "BidModifier":0
            }
         },
         {
            "AdGroupId":5462325568,
            "Level":"AD_GROUP",
            "Type":"SMART_TV_ADJUSTMENT",
            "SmartTvAdjustment":{
               "BidModifier":200,
               "Age":[
                  18,
                  19,
                  20,
                  21
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "AdGroupId":5462325568,
            "Level":"AD_GROUP",
            "Type":"RETARGETING_ADJUSTMENT",
            "RetargetingAdjustment":{
               "RetargetingConditionId":540
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

Inside BidModifiers array can be different Types with different keys. But their name always ends with Adjustment: DesktopAdjustment, SmartTvAdjustment, etc. I need to grab all from these keys and also add Type. I expect this json:
[
   {
      "Type":"DESKTOP_ADJUSTMENT",
      "DesktopAdjustment":{
         "BidModifier":0
      }
   },
   {
      "Type":"SMART_TV_ADJUSTMENT",
      "SmartTvAdjustment":{
         "BidModifier":200,
         "Age":[
            18,
            19,
            20,
            21
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "Type":"RETARGETING_ADJUSTMENT",
      "RetargetingAdjustment":{
         "RetargetingConditionId":540
      }
   }
]

I tried with:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "result": {
        "BidModifiers": {
          "*": {
            "Type": "[&1].Type",
            "*Adjustment": {
              "*": "[#1].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

But it returns invalid result

You just need this shift transformation spec :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "result": {
        "BidModifiers": {
          "*": {
            "Type|*Adjustment": "[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

eg. apply matching from the common level for all those attributes
